Does a negative output DCDC converter need to be isolated?
I was looking for a negative output DC/DC converter. After searching a bit, I found that if I wanted a negative output the DC/DC was always isolated.
For instance, TRACO doesn't offer negative output for its non-isolated DCDC converter:
https://www.tracopower.com/fr/fra/dcdc-converters/non-isoles-0-5-30
I thought as I don't need isolation, why would I pay for isolation that I don't need?
My comprehension is that isolation is a by-product of negative output, other said you can't have negative output without isolation (that is, having a transformer with a "virtual" GND), like so:

Am I right?
I found that TI makes a non-isolated DC/DC converter with negative output, but the architecture is quite non standard:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps84259.pdf?ts=1722957935786&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F


No it doesn't.
Think about generating negative voltages for a minute. There needs to be a way to sink current and regulate that current to a particular voltage. While you don't need isolation to accomplish this, it's an easy way to do it because you can connect one end of the transformer to ground and the transformer sinks current and sends it to ground, all that is needed is a way to monitor the feedback and control the voltage.
There are a few DC DC controllers that can sink current and provide a negative voltage on the output, my favorite series is the CUI 7805 series equivalent  DC DC converters.

https://www.cui.com/product/resource/vx78-1000.pdf
So you can have negative Buck converters, the topology of the inductor/capacitor/diode is different and it sinks current instead of sourcing it:

https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-206.html


After searching a bit, I found that if I wanted a negative output the DCDC was always isolated.

An inverting buck-boost converter is a non-isolated DC-DC converter with a negative output voltage:

Img source and some technical details

I thought as I don't need isolation

Isolation can be a "must". If the input voltage is high (e.g. mains) and the output is direct user-accessible then the isolation can be a safety requirement. A common example is wall chargers: Take the input from the mains (180~265 Vac) and the user has direct access to the output port (e.g. USB), so the isolation is a must here.
Isolation allows you to choose any leg as ground (virtual ground) so the output can be used either as a positive or a negative voltage source.
If you need multiple outputs with a common return path one of which is a negative voltage then an isolated converter can be the most practical and easiest solution. One of the most common examples is an ATX PSU.
The isolation is brought via a transformer which can sometimes make the power supply a bit bulkier but considering the power levels, safety, and practical advantages isolation can be beneficial.
So, the need for isolation depends on the operational requirements such as the ones I mentioned above.
